# Width equal to height

Tags: css

I have a container and children elements. The container is positioned fixed with 10% height. Each child element must have 100% height and width equal to its height - this gets even more complicated when I add that my container is expanding horizontally not vertically. I would like to ask if this is possible using CSS because with JavaScript it could be easily achieved but I'd have to listen for window resizes which is a pain and I would like to avoid that.

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 10%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fdtajx3k/1/

Comment: Try this: http://www.endocreative.com/flexbox-circle-responsive-elements/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might do the trick for you.

On your child `div` elements, use viewport units `vh` for both the width
and height values.

Also, add some bottom padding (optional) on your parent container if the scroll bar is an issue.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 10%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>

  <div>

  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You sir are a genius!